# Multi/hyper-spectral file format that stores band information and meta-data

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-conversion, multi-band

I usually use ERDAS LAN file format drivers to create a multispectral file that contains multiple rasters of different spectral bands. However, I can't find a way to store the information regarding the spectral band acquired by each raster, and when I open the file using, for example, QGIS I can see only the number  of the band (e.g. Band 1, Band 2 etc. etc.) and so it is hard for me to understand which spectral range I am currently using for false colour composting.

I wonder if there are (possibly open-source) file formats allowing storing multispectral raster and metadata for each spectral band collected.

Comment: Won't GeoTIFF do it?

Comment: @nmtoken I used GEOTIFF but still I can't store the band name